# Get value from dropdown and use it

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have been stuck on this problem for the past few days, for the life of me I cannot work out how to navigate from my drop down to an external page with a click of a button in this case an action link. What I have so far:

```
  @Html.DropDownList("DropDown", (SelectList)ViewBag.Test)
  @Html.ActionLink("GO", "Go")
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.DropDown = new SelectList(Services.GetData(), "WebLink", "WebLinkName");                
            return View();
        }

public IEnumerable<Data> Get()
    {
        var db = new conn();
        return db.data;
    }
```

This gives me the result I want, a drop down that shows site names with their weblink stored in `WebLink`

See my working dropdown:

[image]

And where I have inpected it shows the weblink is being stored:
[image]

So what do I need to put in my ActionResult? Below is blank I do not know how to get the weblink value in the Redirect

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Go()
    {
        return Redirect("");// What goes here?
    }
```

Comment: when Go actionresult called by ?

Comment: have you tried by sending parameter to Go actionresult?

Comment: why you are not doing it by Jquery.. it will be easier for you to do it by Jquery

Comment: @RamSingh I am relatively new to Asp.Net I was following the best method I could find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it using below:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Go()
{
    Response.Redirect("www.google.com");
        return null;
}
```

Not tested but, i think it will work for you

if you want to do it by Jquery then you can do it as below:

```
  $('[id$=GO]').on('click', function () {
            var dropdownValue = $('[id$=dropdownList]').val();
            window.location.href = dropdownValue;
        });
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I took a quick crash course in Jquery, this is doing the job.Thanks